# Compiling angular does not work until a model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm hoping that there is a fairly simple solution.

I have a directive set up that loads HTML from a file. It's then supposed to compile that HTML using Angular. The directive:

```
angular.module('wc.directives', [], function($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.directive('view', function($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(
        function(scope) {
           // watch the 'view' expression for changes
          return scope.$eval(attrs.view);
        },
        function(value) {
          // when the 'view' expression changes
          $.ajax({
            url: '/partials/' + value,
            success: function(data) {
              element.html(data);
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
          });
        }
      );
    };
  });
});
```

An example of a something that this is supposed to load (in jade)

```
input#nameInput.nameField(ng-model='name', type='text')
h1 {{ name }}
```

When the page loads, {{ name }} is visible. However, when you start typing in the text field, the {{ name }} updates to whatever you are typing.

If the `element.html` and `$compile` statements are not inside the ajax `success` callback, then everything compiles as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple solution, as expected.

I just needed to add `scope.$apply();` after the `$compile` statement.

EDIT: The better solution is using `$http`. Here's the final working code:

```
angular.module('wc.directives', [], function($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.directive('view', function($compile, $http) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(
        function(scope) {
           // watch the 'view' expression for changes
          return scope.$eval(attrs.view);
        },
        function(value) {
          // when the 'view' expression changes
          if (value !== null) {
            $http.get('/partials/' + value).success(function(data) {
              element.html(data);
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
          }
        }
      );
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are making your life harder by using jQuery's `ajax`. Drop it in favor of AngularJS `$http` and you won't need to call `$apply` (as `$http` will do it for you!).

In short - **unless you've got very particular reasons to use jQuery's `ajax` drop it and use `$http` instead**.

Comment: $http is the first thing I tried, but I didn't know how to inject it properly. I went back to figure out how to inject it properly and it works nicely, thanks!